# Fields in a report browsable but not searchable?

Tags: force.com, reporting

One of my users is trying to build a report with the report "Opportunities with Contact Roles." It's a standard report, I think.

when they search to add the field to the report it doesn't come up, BUT it's there when they scroll down.... FWIW, all profiles have  write access to that field.

what's going on?

Comment: I've seen this happen when the Field Name has underscores in places of Spaces, FWIW.  In some cases if I type "Contact" I will NOT find "MTI_Visible_Contact_ID" in the field list in a report, but it's there in the list (had to do the underscores for this normally hidden field due to the way an Addon we use works).

Comment: FWIW this field label did not have any underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a cause- the field label had leading white spaces. AGH!

I thought SF truncated leading/trailing whitespaces